# Signal flow simplification

Tags: signal, control-system

I've looked at the various simplifications that can be made for signal flaw diagrams to combine branches; however, I can't work out how one can apply a transformation to simplify the following configuration.

[image: signal flow]

Comment: Where did you get this image? Is this about FSMs?

Comment: Do you want \$\frac{X_4}{X_1}\$?

Comment: It's not a FSM, it's a signal flow diagram.  I made the image.  It's used in DSP, electronics and control systems.

Yes, I want $\frac{X_4}{X_1}$, but rather, I want to know how one can simplify the above to get $\frac{X_4}{X_1}$.  Not just get a bunch of simultaneous equations and solve for it.

Comment: IMHO, to solve X4/X1, the fastest way is the [Mason's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason%27s_gain_formula).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few rules you need to know in order to simplify this,

1. Branch Move Rule:

[image]

and Negative feedback Rule, which says that a system of the form shown below

[image]

has transfer function

$$
T = \frac{Y}{X} = \frac{a}{1 + ab}
$$

To solve your problem you have to move the X2 node to the right across G2 then move the X3 node to the left across G2.After that you then use the Negative feedback rule to get the transfer functions of different portions of the signal flow diagram then multiply them out to get your final transfer function.

You should get something along the lines of

$$
T = \frac{X_4}{X_1} = G_2 \frac{G1}{1 + G_1G_2G_3} \frac{G3}{1 + \frac{G_3G_5}{G_2}} 
$$